# How would I integrate following trigonometric function $\displaystyle\int \sin^3(x) \,\operatorname{d}x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to evaluate
$$\displaystyle\int \sin^3(x) \,\operatorname{d}x$$ 
without using integration by parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$\sin^{2n+1}x=\sin x(1-\cos^2x)^n$$

Set $\cos x=u$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\int \sin^3(x) \,\operatorname{d}x=\int \left[\sin(x)\right]\left[1-\cos^2(x)\right] \,\operatorname{d}x$$

Then, use the substitution, $t=\cos(x)$.

Comment: Alternatively you could multiply out the terms in the integral and note that $-\sin x \cos^2 x = 1/3 d/dx ( \cos^3 x )$ and then use the FTC for that part of the integral.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. You may just write
$$
\sin^3 x=\sin x \times \sin^2 x=\sin x \times (1- \cos^2 x).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $t:=\cos x$
$$\implies \int\sin^3x dx=\int (t^2-1)dt=t^3/3-t+c=\frac13\cos^3x-\cos x+c.$$